# 'app-element' is not a known element in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, plotly

I want to display a graph.

In the chart.component.ts file I wrote the data for plotting the graph:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js';


PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-element',
  templateUrl: './element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./element.component.scss']
})
export class ElementComponent implements OnInit {

      public graph = {
        data: [
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 6, 3], type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines+points', marker: {color: 'red'} },
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 5, 3], type: 'bar' },
        ],
        layout: {width: 320, height: 240, title: 'A Fancy Plot'}
    };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

}
The html looks like this:

```
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>
```

Then I want to render this graph in another component.
I create a dashboard.component.ts

```
<app-element></app-element>
```

Then when I try ng serve

An error occurs:

> If 'app-heatmap' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part
> of this module.
> 2. If 'app-element' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
> to suppress this message.
>
> ```
> 2 <app-element></app-element>
> ```

Seems I forgot one step?

Comment: Are you declaring that component in a `declarations` on a `@NgModule` any where?

Comment: The error is indicates that there's some other component that's causing the issue, not the one you've displayed. Is there another component with a selector called "app-heatmap" that you haven't declared in a module?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you forget declare your component in the main.module, see the docs about modules: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

Comment: @Eden1998 make sure you have added component in `declarations` array of module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities are here

**1. Both elements are in same module**

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [AppElementComponent, ParentComopnent]
    ...
})
```

**2. Both are in different Modules**

**AppComponentModule**

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [AppElementComponent],
    exports: [AppElementComponent]
    ...
})
```

**ParentComponentModule**

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [ParentComponent],
    imports: [AppComponentModule],
    ...
})
```

Comment: thanks, this should be on my cheatsheet, great overview!

Answer (score 3):

Add `ElementComponent` to the `declarations` array within your default module (usually `app.module.ts`)

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ElementComponent
    ...
  ]
...
```